# Scroll View with Drawer Layout and View Pager Android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout, drawerlayout

I have a `drawer layout` in the main view I want to make the main view under `scroll view`.
I wrapped my relative layout into a linear layout to put it in scroll view but doesn't work.

---

The main view contains image slider and `view pager` under the first tab which doesn't fit on the page and needs scrolling.
Adding Scroll view to only the list isn't an option and the list is a linear layout, not a listview. 
Here's my layout file.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                        android:id="@+id/slider"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="220dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

                    <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
                        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                      android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        custom:selected_color="#ffa500"
                        custom:selected_height="10dp"
                        custom:selected_padding_left="4dp"
                        custom:selected_padding_right="4dp"
                        custom:selected_width="10dp"
                        custom:shape="rect"
                        custom:unselected_color="#ffffff"
                        custom:unselected_height="10dp"
                        custom:unselected_padding_left="4dp"
                        custom:unselected_padding_right="4dp"
                        custom:unselected_width="10dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_sliding_menu"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice">

        </ListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here's image of the output a nonscroll-able view   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEmMr.png]

Comment: Do you want just the list to scroll or the layout including the image slider, view pager and list?

Comment: The layout including the image slider, view pager and list.

Comment: Then why have you kept the list view outside the scroll view?

Comment: The listview is for sliding menu not the list under the view pager

Comment: Try wrapping the whole layout with scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Use NestedScrollView It will help You

http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/07/nested-scroll-views-in-android.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

**Or**

You have to add your main_content view as a ListView Header.

https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-listview-header.html

https://blograchita.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/listview-with-header-footer-view-android/

Hope it will help you...

Comment: I don't use list view I'm using Linear Layout because list views inside scroll view don't work well.

Comment: Ur not using ListView means, what is this  **lv_sliding_menu**

Comment: List view for the side menu

Comment: The list view only is in the side menu other objects are in the main UI.